# UnicodeWarning (equal comparison failed to convert both args) on pandas assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, unicode, xlrd

I'm assigning a scalar value to a new column in pandas:

`df[col] = srs[some_index]`

I have a warnings.simplefilter("error", UnicodeWarning) in place to catch what would otherwise be a warning (that's an irritant I could probably turn off if I understood what was happening and was comfortable ignoring it).

Here's the traceback I get:

```
  File "/my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2299, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2367, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
  File "/my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1208, in _set_item
    self._data.set(key, value)
  File "/my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3331, in set
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/my_virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1759, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3979)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 152, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3782)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 178, in pandas.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates (pandas/index.c:4213)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 195, in pandas.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer (pandas/index.c:4469)
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

FWIW, the data in df and srs both originate from Excel sheets (grabbed using pandas.read_excel()). It's likely (because it doesn't happen with all spreadsheets) that there's a non-ascii, unicode character in the data somewhere. Without figuring out exactly which piece of data is blowing it up, I'd like to just make the code robust to that situation.

Any advice?

**EDIT** Additional thing(s) I've tried:

- `df[unicode(col)] = srs[unicode(some_index)]`

**LATER EDIT** Additional manifestation (that generates substantially the same error) that my provided solution does *not* fix:

- `df.ix[df.my_col.astype(unicode).eq(""), "my_col"] = 0.0`
- In response to [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356307/jens) comment re: type() and bytes() (because the input is coming from read_excel(), which I believe uses xlrd), the below could be indicative of what's going on:

(Apparently I need a non-bulleted list item line for the code sample below to show up correctly.)

```
ipdb> type(df.my_col.astype(unicode).iloc[0])
<type 'unicode'>
ipdb> bytes(df.my_col.astype(unicode).iloc[0])
'50000'
```

**`'50000'` apparently is not a unicode object, which would look like `u'50000'`**

If this is indeed the problem, is there an easy fix or does it depend on the developer(s) of xlrd?

Comment: does `df[col] = srs[some_index].values[0]` work?

Comment: No, because srs is a pandas.Series, not a pandas.DataFrame. Therefore, srs[some_index] has no attribute "values".

Comment: OK how about `df[col] = srs[some_index][0]`?

Comment: That's going to return the first character of whatever the value is (assuming it's a string), which is not the desired result. I want the whole value.

Comment: Can you get the `type()` and actual `bytes()` of both values? I've seen similar issues with data from office applications when characters (i.e. byte values) didn't map to proper unicode pages.

Comment: The data definitely includes Excel-sourced information, so that sounds like a promising lead (though I haven't had a chance to test it yet). I'm using pandas.read_excel() to consumer it, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

This got rid of the error, but the solution feels incomplete and I'd like to better understand the real problem:

`df[str(col)] = srs[some_index]`